# Is it possible to stop pouchDB replicating all revisions from a remote CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

As I understand it doing a `localDB.replicate.from(remoteDB)` will cause PouchDB to get all document revisions into the localDB.

Is there some way to make `replicate.from` only replicate/get the most recent version of every document, and only keep one revision of each document? I only ever do a `replicate.from` and never a `replicate.to`. I have some large documents in the remoteDB which get updated every week and want to minimise the amount of space that the `localDB` takes up.

I have set the `localDB` to `auto_compact` but I think this only affects documents that are created locally and not documents replicated from the remote DB?

Comment: Could a [filtered replication](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#filtered-replication) work for your use case?

Comment: Actually by default only leaf revisions are replicated. Meaning only winning and any conflicting revisions. What may have confused you is the revision history replication. But this history is nothing more than ID & REVISION pairs.

Comment: So if a document gets revised in the remote db I will still only have one revision of the document in PouchDB?